# Conjunction "as much as" in sentence

Tags: conjunctions

> **A:** You can eat the food as much as you can eat.
>   **B:** You can eat as much food as you can.

In which sentence above is the position of *food* correct?

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is not grammatically correct.

The second sentence – "You can eat as much food as you can" – is grammatically correct but not well expressed.

The problem with the word "can" is that it that means both "permitted to" and "capable of".

Therefore, to avoid ambiguity and to express the sentence politely, it would be better:

- to replace the first "can" with "may" or "are welcome to"; and
- to replace the second "can" with "like" or "wish".

Also, it is not necessary to use "food" as this is understood.

You would then end up with well-spoken phrases such as the following.

- "You **may** eat as much as you **like**".
- "You **may** eat as much as you **wish**."
- "You **are welcome** to eat as much as you **would like** to."

By phrasing it as suggested above, the phrase ends up meaning "There is plenty of food; please do not hesitate; you are permitted to eat as much food as you would like to eat".